# How to UV unwrap this object and how to have the same textures resolution for the two objects

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm a beginner in UV Unwrapping, I don't find the good way to UV unwrap this part of my object, it's called 'Detail' in the Blend file.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried different technics but I didn't get the best results to maintain the same resolution for the two objects, because I want them to share the same UV layout after.
Please, could you help me to find the solution? Thank you in advance :)

[image]

Comment: could you please precise what you mean by "maintain the same resolution for the two objects"?

Comment: when I put textures on the two objects, it looks stretched and low res on the 'Detail' object because I must resized its UV islands as it was out of the UV map :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm guessing you mean relative UV scale between the two separate mesh objects when you say same resolution.

But first we need to clarify what you mean by "share the same UV layout after".
Do you
A. mean that you want the UVs to overlap or sit on top of each other in the UV space like this.

[image]

Or B.

Have their own separate islands but on the same UV map like this

[image]

I got this result by using blender 2.8 new feature that allows going into edit mode of multiple meshes at once and a combination. of uv mapping operation.

So in edit mode of both mesh objects, first using project from view, from the back with just the faces along the center point of mesh since its a mirrored mesh. Then using constrain to proportions, move to one side, then move to center using snapping to align that center line of mesh with center of x axis like in screenshots. Making sure when you scale them to scale them together.

Next I take all those uvs in the uv editor and hit p to pin them in place (the red verts in UV editor), then select all faces, and run unwrap. This will keep the pinned UV verts in place and fill in the rest linked faces with usual unwrapping.

Then we can use the mirror modifier setting for flip U to automatically mirror the UV to the other side like this.

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a5dIbtKAD47t3x--GEjsx9qR0oqUPT-V/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer :) I mean B: same islands but sharing the same UV map (not UV layout as I said, I'm sorry). And it's really difficult when the Solidify modifier is applied. Because I want to export it to another soft for texturing.